# How to get rid of goitrogens from goitrogenic foods without cooking?

Tags: salad

Cruciferous vegetables like cabbage, Brussels sprouts, broccoli, broccolini, cauliflower, mustard greens, kale, turnips, and collard greens contain goitrogens. Is there a way to get rid of these without cooking. I eat those vegetables daily in salad.

Comment: We don't answer questions regarding health claims, so I removed the health-related parts from your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Gamma Radiation](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02542009?no-access=true)... not practical, but it would inactivate the enzyme that leads to goitrogenic activity in most Brassicae.  The majority of these vegetables are really only very slightly goitrogenic because the possible thyroid inhibiting substance, goitrin, is bound up in progoitrin, an inactive compound.